# Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

i want to refresh the product page when i press AddtoWishlist button. But when i pressed the button it has error.

here is the code

```php
 <?php
$wishlistData = DB::table('wishlist')->rightJoin('products', 'wishlist.pro_id', '=', 'products.id')->where('wishlist.pro_id', '=',$productdata->id)->get();

$count = App\wishList::where(['pro_id' => $productdata->id])->count();

 if($count=="0"){?>

  <form action="{{url('/addToWishList')}}" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <input type="hidden" value="{{$productdata->id}}"  name="pro_id"/>
  <button type="submit" value="Add to WishList" class="wishlist-btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i><span>Add to WishList</span></button>
  </form>

<?php } else {?>

  <h5>Added to Wishlist<a href="{{url('/wishlist')}}"> wishlist</a></h5>

<?php }

?>
```

This is the controller function of the add to wishlist button

```php
public function  addWishList(Request $request)
    {

        $wishList = new wishList;
        $wishList->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $wishList->pro_id = $request->pro_id;

        $wishList->save();

        $productdata = DB::table('products')->where('id',$request->pro_id)->get();
        return view('product',compact('productdata'));
    }
```

Comment: Please post your error messages.

Comment: Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see ```category``` in your code.  I think u missing some code that forget to  post.

Comment: And I guess the ```category``` has many ```products```, so in that view. there is a ```products_data``` get ```category```. but you have ```product_datas```, and you don't use loop. so u get this error, I think.

Comment: Collections contain many items in them ... you want the `category` property from one of those items, not the collection itself ..... you can find a million questions on here where people have the same misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

There is no category in all code so something is missing, it might be in App\wishList check it out.

I Advice you to read more about MVC, Eloquent and Laravel, as you are asking for data in View while it should be in Controller, Class names initials should be capital like WishList and in your case why would you use DB::table when you have eloquent relations.